# Finding cycle in Aho-Corasick automaton

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'am facing a problem which should be solved using Aho-Corasick automaton. I'am given a set of words (composed with '0' or '1') - patterns and I must decide if it is possible to create infinite text, which wouldn't contain any of given patterns. I think, the solution is to create Aho-Corasick automaton and search for a cycle without matching states, but I'm not able to propose a good way to do that. I thought of searching the states graph using DFS, but I'm not sure if it will work and I have an implementation problem - let's assume, that we are in a state, which has an '1' edge - but state pointed by that edge is marked as matching - so we cannot use that edge, we can try fail link (current state doesn't have '0' edge) - but we must also remember, that we could not go with '1' edge from state pointed by fail link of the current one.

Could anyone correct me and show me how to do that? I've written Aho-Corasick in C++ and I'am sure it works - I also understand the entire algorithm.

Here is the base code:

```
class AhoCorasick
{

static const int ALPHABET_SIZE = 2;

struct State
{
  State* edge[ALPHABET_SIZE];
  State* fail;
  State* longestMatchingSuffix;
  //Vector used to remember which pattern matches in this state.
  vector< int > matching;
  short color;

  State()
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; ++i)
      edge[i] = 0;
    color = 0;
  }

  ~State()
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; ++i)
    {
      delete edge[i];
    }
  }
};

private:
  State root;
  vector< int > lenOfPattern;
  bool isFailComputed;

  //Helper function used to traverse state graph.
  State* move(State* curr, char letter)
  {
    while(curr != &root && curr->edge[letter] == 0)
    {
      curr = curr->fail;
    }
    if(curr->edge[letter] != 0)
      curr = curr->edge[letter];
    return curr;
  }

  //Function which computes fail links and longestMatchingSuffix. 
  void computeFailLink()
  {
    queue< State* > Q;
    root.fail = root.longestMatchingSuffix = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; ++i)
    {
      if(root.edge[i] != 0)
      {
        Q.push(root.edge[i]);
        root.edge[i]->fail = &root;
      }
    }
    while(!Q.empty())
    {
      State* curr = Q.front();
      Q.pop();
      if(!curr->fail->matching.empty())
      {
        curr->longestMatchingSuffix = curr->fail;
      }
      else
      {
        curr->longestMatchingSuffix = curr->fail->longestMatchingSuffix;
      }
      for(int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; ++i)
      {
        if(curr->edge[i] != 0)
        {
          Q.push(curr->edge[i]);
          State* state = curr->fail;
          state = move(state, i);
          curr->edge[i]->fail = state;
        }
      }
    }
    isFailComputed = true;
  }

public:
  AhoCorasick()
  {
    isFailComputed = false;
  }

  //Add pattern to automaton.
  //pattern - pointer to pattern, which will be added
  //fun - function which will be used to transform character to 0-based index.
  void addPattern(const char* const pattern, int (*fun) (const char *))
  {
    isFailComputed = false;
    int len = strlen(pattern);
    State* curr = &root;
    const char* pat = pattern;
    for(; *pat; ++pat)
    {
      char tmpPat = fun(pat);
      if(curr->edge[tmpPat] == 0)
      {
        curr = curr->edge[tmpPat] = new State;
      }
      else
      {
        curr = curr->edge[tmpPat];
      }
    }
    lenOfPattern.push_back(len);
    curr->matching.push_back(lenOfPattern.size() - 1);
  }
};

int alphabet01(const char * c)
{
  return *c - '0';
}
```

Comment: Please post a sketch of your code that builds the automaton (not the full code please - just the key parts): it might be easy to modify the code to look for cycles as it builds the automaton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't look through your code, but I know very simple and efficient implementation.

First of all, lets add Dictionary Suffix Links to the tree (their description you can find in Wikipedia). Then you have to look through all your tree and somehow mark matching nodes and nodes that have Dict Suffix Links as bad nodes. The explanation of these actions is obvious: you don't need all the matching nodes, or nodes that have a matching suffix in them.

Now you have an Aho-Corasick tree without any matching nodes. If you just run DFS algo on the resulting tree, you will get what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Dictionary Suffix Links, but I'm pretty sure, that I do exactly what you said - few days before yours reply I've implemented something like this - but it was not working - few days from now I realised why - I was ommiting cycles which were constructed using only one letter.

Comment: Well done. By Dictionary Suffix Links I meant links that point to the previous suffix which is the full word.